# Access App Info From Watch

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

Im a bit new to IOS and Swift. I generally use Cordova and let the "magic" behind the curtains unfold when building IOS apps. It seems, however, that developing for Apple Watch using watch kit isn't so "magical".

What I am trying to do is access authentication information via my watch, that was entered into my IOS app; then utilize that info to make API requests which I will parse and present in the apple watch. I don't want users to authenticate using the watch, hence there is some handshaking that needs to be done. Please help, not sure where to get started...

Comment: You could use WCSession's 'sendMessage' function to ask the phone for credentials. https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchconnectivity/wcsession

Comment: Thanks Jordan, I will look into that for sure. Just trying to get general ideas for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I used MMWormholeSession with Cordova in conjuction with WCSession. I had to do some modifications to the MMWormhole code, but all the puzzle pieces were in there.